# Add left right swipe function to webview

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, windows-10

So I have a custom webview showing a web page from a site and want to add left and right swipes to ease in quicker navigation.  I have the controls as buttons but want to add a left and right swipe.

SO I found [this video on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yGs6FuUKpkg) that I have implemented just fine, and it works as long as I don't load up a url page.

```
<Page
x:Class="test_storage.SecondPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:test_storage"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Grid Background="WhiteSmoke">
     <WebView Name="webview" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
</Grid>
```

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    Windows.Storage.ApplicationDataContainer localSettings;
    int x1;
    int x2;


    public SecondPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        webview.ManipulationMode = ManipulationModes.TranslateRailsX | ManipulationModes.TranslateRailsY;
        webview.ManipulationStarted += (s, e) => x1 = (int)e.Position.X;

        webview.ManipulationCompleted += (s, e) =>
        {
            x2 = (int)e.Position.X;

            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(x1);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(x2);

            if (x1  > x2)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("right");
            };
            if (x1 < x2 )
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("left");

            }

        };
    }
}
```

I understand from the webview class that I can not add Manipulation events as they are not supported for the webview class.  So like in the YouTube tutorial I added an image with opacity=0 and added the Manipulation events to that object, but still it will not work.

So just taking a step back, is it possible to get the functionality I am after to swipe left and right on a webview.

As said, if I don't load up a page on the webview, it works but as soon as a page loads then it stops working.

Why would loading a web url stop the Manipulation events from working?   How do I fix it and get it working?

Thanks for any help.

EDITED:

Here is the OnNavigatedTo menthod that once included stops the left right swipe function.

```
 protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        Uri webUrl = new Uri("http://www.abc.net.au");
        webview.Navigate(webUrl);

    }
```

Comment: The code you show doesn't match your description of it. Where's the image?

Comment: Added the OnNavigatedTo method.  I cant show anything for the xaml as it says "This element is enabled only when the application is running".  Please let me know what image you then want and I will include it.  Thanks for the response too, much appreciated.